# Language switch in web.py forms

Tags: python, web.py

I implemented language switch ( from [runtime-language switch](http://webpy.org/cookbook/runtime-language-switch)).
It works but not for forms (my forms are in separate file 'forms.py').

It looks forms are initialized during the start of application and use only default localization.

How to reload forms during language switching,  how to force it?

Best regards,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I think this blog can help you!

http://blog.est.im/post/34342180038

This is my `test_run.py`in web.py project.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from code import app

# code.py is my main file

def dev_server():
    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from django.utils import autoreload
    autoreload.main(dev_server)
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this particular problem I had to subclass web.py form and change its methods to use _() when outputting notes and descriptions.

To mark these strings as translatable I defined N_ function and wrapped it over strings in form/validator definitions.